# how google map show details of map in every zoom?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

i want to create a complex Electronic circuit in HTML.i want to show every details of circuit in each zoom(  in different zoom different detail of circuit. like google map )

i want to know how google map works and how add details in every zoom with high performance (browser doesn't become slow ) ??

Answer (score 0):

For satellite view or custom overlays ,Google maps has different overlays depending on the zoom level. If you are in zoom 10 then it render detailled overlay images, if you are in zoom 5 it render undetailled images. All images are stored in a server.

For the roads and points it's different. Roads are described with pathes, like a vectorial object (SVG...) so the same road is drawn at each zoom level with lat and lng.

You should take a look at custom overlays. There is good examples of people using them not for map but for different things.

You can take a look at this for the image part : https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-google-maps-api-and-custom-overlays--webdesign-13868